# Como trabalhar no mesmo banco de dados pelo workbench e pelo terminal?

Tags: mysql, terminal, osx, mac

Criei um banco de dados pelo workbench

[image: print do BD do Workbench]

Mas não consigo encontrá-lo pelo terminal do Mac. Como trabalhar no mesmo banco de dados? Como localizar o banco de dados criado pelo workbench? E vice-versa...

Estou me conectando pelo comando `mysql -h localhost -u root -p` através do terminal.

[image: print tela terminal]

Comment: Poste como você está tentando se conectar, e o erro exibido.

Comment: Para começo de conversa, sou iniciante e estou fazendo um curso de BD. Fiz um servidor na minha máquina pelo MAMP e depois criei o banco de dados pelo Workbench . Agora estou tentando trabalhar pelo terminal. Instalei o MySQL mas não consigo trabalhar no mesmo BD criado pelo Workbench.

Comment: Tranquilo Júlio ! Acho que sei o que é, então vou postar na resposta para irmos acompanhando.

Answer (score 1):

O que deve estar acontecendo, é que você deve estar tentando conectar da seguinte forma:

```
mysql -u usuario -p senha -h localhost database_name
```

O correto seria:

```
 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -u usuario -p senha
```

Assim você puxa a instância do MAMP e não a local (provavelmente tenha instalado o mysql localmente)

Ou até pode estar acontecendo o contrário, de você estar conectando na instância com o Workbench, e pelo terminal no MAMP.

**Mais alternativas:**

Trocar a porta do Mysql no MAMP, e conectar da seguinte forma:

```
mysql --host=localhost --port=9999 mysql -u root -p
```

Verificar a porta da sua instância e ver se é a do MAMP:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Deu certo!Usei o comando da segunda sugestão e deu certo. Agora preciso me informar mais sobre o conceito de "instâncias" de um banco de dados.

Comment: Opa ! Jóia @JulioBarreto ! Não esqueça de marcar como resolvido ! :]